# Building a program using pyqtdeploy

Tags: python, qt, pyqtdeploy

I am experimenting compile a program that was created using python 2.7.3.  I usually use PyInstaller which works great, but want to experiment building the same program using pyqtdeploy.  I followed the minimal instructions provided by the website, and was able to solve most encountered issues.  However, one error keeps coming that I can't solve.  I keep getting this error message:

**LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'sip.lib'**

I could not find any information about the sip.lib file and a search of internet did not help. 
1. Where I can find a copy of the sip.lib file?
2. Are there a better clearer instructions on using pyqtdeploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this error to go away by checking the "sip" checkbox under the "PyQt Modules" tab:

[image]